# Retrieve input from multiple text fields with JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, textfield

Using JavaFX, Ive created 4 text fields a user can input information. I then have a button, when pressed, will save the user's input to a text file where the user can select the location to save to. 
I can't figure out how to retrieve the user's input from each of the individual fields. 
Im using a fxml with a controller class which is here.

```
package application;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.System.Logger;
import java.lang.System.Logger.Level;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.stage.FileChooser;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MainController {

@FXML
private Button Button1;
@FXML
private Button Button2;

@FXML
private ListView listview;
@FXML
private TextField Name;
@FXML
private TextField DoB;
@FXML
private TextField Address;
@FXML
private TextField Exp;

public void Button1Action(ActionEvent event) {
    FileChooser fc = new FileChooser();
    File selectedFile = fc.showOpenDialog(null);

    if (selectedFile != null) {
        listview.getItems().add(selectedFile.getName());
    } else {
        System.out.println("File is not valid");
    }

}

public void Button2Action(ActionEvent e) {
    String name = name.getText(Name);
}

}
```

Here is the fxml

```
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ListView?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" 
minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" 
xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/9.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" 
fx:controller="application.MainController">
<children>
  <Button fx:id="Button1" layoutX="90.0" layoutY="72.0" 
mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#Button1Action" text="File Explorer" />
  <ListView fx:id="listview" layoutX="300.0" layoutY="27.0" 
prefHeight="346.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
  <TextField fx:id="DoB" layoutX="131.0" layoutY="238.0" />
  <TextField fx:id="Address" layoutX="131.0" layoutY="274.0" />
  <TextField fx:id="Exp" layoutX="131.0" layoutY="310.0" />
  <TextField fx:id="Name" layoutX="131.0" layoutY="200.0" />
  <Button fx:id="Button2" layoutX="159.0" layoutY="348.0" 
mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#Button2Action" text="Print Paycheck" />
  <Label layoutX="15.0" layoutY="204.0" text="Name" />
  <Label layoutX="14.0" layoutY="242.0" text="Date of Birth" />
  <Label layoutX="15.0" layoutY="278.0" text="Address" />
  <Label layoutX="15.0" layoutY="314.0" text="Years of Experience" />
</children>
</AnchorPane>
```

EDIT:

I have been able to write the input to a text and save it per the user's desire. 
but the text in the file isnt on new lines and not spaced

```
    FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
    fileChooser.setTitle("Save file");
    fileChooser.getExtensionFilters().add(new ExtensionFilter("Text Files", 
"*.txt"));
    File saveFile = fileChooser.showSaveDialog(window);

    FileWriter writer;
    try {
        writer = new FileWriter(saveFile);
        BufferedWriter buf = new BufferedWriter(writer);

        buf.write(name.getText() + "\n ");
        buf.write(dob.getText() + "\n ");
        buf.write(address.getText() + "\n ");
        buf.write(exp.getText() + "\n ");
        buf.flush();
        buf.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

`String name = name.getText(Name);` should be changed to `String name = Name.getText()`. If you do something similar to that with each textfield, you should be able to get their contents.

Edit:
to prompt the user for where they want to save their text file and what to call it, you can use a [`FileChooser`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/FileChooser.html), which you can use like this:

```
FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
fileChooser.setTitle("Save File");
fileChooser.getExtensionFilters().add(new ExtensionFilter("Text Files", "*.txt"));
Window window = Button1.getScene().getWindow();
File saveFile = fileChooser.showSaveDialog(window);
```

and then use normal file IO stuff to write what you want to the file.

Code Review sidenote, which you are free to ignore:
It's considered good practice in Java to name your variables starting with lowercase letters and your Classes with uppercase letters. This makes it obvious at first glance whether a method is being called on an instance of an object or on a class.

Comment: Awesome. Got that working and printed out the results to console to ensure it works.
Now to have it prompt the user to save it to a text file and select the location

Comment: Edited OP. its not putting each field on new lines even thouhg I have "\n".

Comment: instead of writing "\n" try `buf.newLine()` from the documentation on BufferedWriter here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html#newLine--

Comment: Is there a possible way to pass the entered text from the MainController class into another class in order to use that data in another way? file IO with java is quite new for me

Answer (score -1):

You can create an array of Text Fields. create a vbox instead of ListView then add text fields to vbox children in a for loop.

another option is using listview. [if you have few text fields use vbox instead of listview]